# Making sure every line ends with punctuation

Tags: python, unix, nltk

I grabbed text corpora from the nltk and now want to process it to make sure every line in file ends with a punctuation marker.

```
Her mother
had died too long ago for her to
remember her caresses; and her place had been supplied
by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short
of a mother in affection.
```

Should become:

```
Her mother had died too long ago for her to remember her caresses; 
and her place had been supplied by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short of a mother in affection.
```

I tried sed to match if no punctuation at end of line, but can't figure out how to move up the next line.  Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it the module that you are having trouble with or the logic of your code loop?

Comment: How can you tell where the linebreak happens? Shouldn't another line come after `governess,` ?

Comment: @adsmith: I decided to ignore mid-line punctuation if it's followed by more text, as it'll simply be too difficult to process.

Comment: @sshashank124 the logic of the code loop

Comment: @user1899415 what is your code so far? How are you accessing this text, etc? Shouldn't be too tough.

Comment: You can set the text to have a limit on the max number of characters on a line. Then if a sentence overshoots,  check the last character of each word (convert into list with split) and if punctuation, add "\n" to that word string.

Comment: I'm accessing from a text file, I tried `sed 's/$/./' filename` which puts a period at the end of every line, but isn't exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you use `paste` and `sed` like this?

`paste` prints all the text in the same line.

```
$ paste -s -d' ' file
Her mother had died too long ago for her to remember her caresses; and her place had been supplied by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short of a mother in affection.
```

`sed` that adds a new line after every `.` and `;`.

```
$ paste -s -d' ' file | sed -r 's/(\.|\;) /\1\n/g'
Her mother had died too long ago for her to remember her caresses;
and her place had been supplied by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short of a mother in affection.
```

Comment: I'd take care here as it doesn't really satisfy your conditions as-is. An in-line `.` or `;` will still wrap, contrary to your original conditions.

Answer (score 3):

In Python:

```
import string # for string.punctuation

with open("path/to/file") as f:
    output = ""
    for line in f:
        sanitized = line.strip()
        output += sanitized
        if sanitized[-1] in string.punctuation:
            output += "\n"
```

After the `with` block terminates, `output` will be the file as intended. You can then overwrite the file with `output` if you need it to stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

With NLTK's `sent_tokenize()`:

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize
>>> text = """Her mother
... had died too long ago for her to
... remember her caresses; and her place had been supplied
... by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short
... of a mother in affection."""
>>> sent_tokenize(text.replace("\n", " "))
['Her mother had died too long ago for her to remember her caresses; and her place had been supplied by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short of a mother in affection.']
```